# Chart.js StackedBar error : this.labelsFilter is not a function

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js version 1.0.2 and Chart.StackedBar.js and I have this error :

```
chart.js:1995 Uncaught TypeError: this.labelsFilter is not a function(anonymous function) @ chart.js:1995
helpers.each @ chart.js:204
Chart.Scale.Chart.Element.extend.draw @ chart.js:1992
Chart.Type.extend.draw @ Chart.StackedBar.js:534
animationFrame @ chart.js:720
```

This is my Code (with KnockoutJS):

```
var dbData = {
labels: ko.utils.arrayMap(self.labelArrays(), function (data) { return data; }),
datasets: ko.utils.arrayMap(self.labelArrays(), function (
return {
label: label,
fillColor: '#fillColor',
strokeColor: "#strokeColor",
highlightFill: '#highlightFillColor',
highlightStroke: '#highlightStrokeColor',
data: self.getValueArraysByLabel(label)
}
})
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext("2d");
window.Chart1 = new Chart(ctx).StackedBar(dbData, { responsive: true });
```

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please show your code that calls chart.js and generates this error

Comment: might be a typo - but a variable named label does not exist (in your example code)

Comment: i'm sorry, it exist
datasets: ko.utils.arrayMap(self.labelArrays(), function (label) { ... }